# Scrapy won't download files with the standard Files Pipeline

Tags: python, web-crawler, scapy

I'm trying to download all the files from a college [Moodle](https://github.com/moodle/moodle),  which are organized by course. I have managed to successfully login  and locate all links of the files in the correct order; when i pass the links to the `parse_files` function, nothing gets downloaded and i got this output:

```
    2018-07-11 21:56:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET     https://moodle.some.ac.il/course/view.php?id=1032> (referer: https://moodle.some.ac.il/my/)
        2018-07-11 21:56:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://moodle.some.ac.il/course/view.php?id=1032>
        {'files_urls': ['https://moodle.some.ac.il/course/view.php?id=1032#section-0']}2018-07-11 21:56:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-07-11 21:56:44 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 5944,
 'downloader/request_count': 18,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 17,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 220875,
 'downloader/response_count': 18,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 16,
 'downloader/response_status_count/303': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 11, 18, 56, 44, 591156),
 'item_scraped_count': 13,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 32,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 53354496,
 'memusage/startup': 53354496,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 16,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 17,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 17,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 17,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 17,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 11, 18, 56, 37, 753571)}
2018-07-11 21:56:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Im using the builtin files pipeline after enable it and set `FILES_STORE = 'files'`in my settings. i might be missing something or maybe is relate to the fact that each file link `https://moodle.some.ac.il/course/view.php?id=1032#section-0` points to `https://moodle.some.ac.il/pluginfile.php/44033/mod_resource/content/1/my_file.docx` and the spider doesn't manage to resolve the redirection link? perhaps is there any better approach? Thanks a lot. here is my spider:

```
import scrapy
import os
import college_files.items as my_item


class CollegeSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = 'college_spider'

start_urls = ['https://moodle.somecollege.com']


if not os.path.exists('files'):
    os.makedirs("files")



def parse(self, response):

    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'username': 'my_username', 'password': 'my_password'},
            callback=self.after_login
    )

def after_login(self, response):
    user_name = response.xpath('//div/header/div/div/h1/text()').extract()

    cursos_first = response.css('div.well')
    if not os.path.exists(myFilesDir):
        os.makedirs(myFilesDir)

    for my_course in cursos_first.css('a'):
        my_course_dir = os.path.join(myFilesDir, my_course.css('a::text').extract_first())

        if not os.path.exists(my_course_dir):
            os.makedirs(my_course_dir)
        yield response.follow(my_course.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first(), callback=self.parse_files)
        print("Despues1 {0}".format(my_course))


def parse_files(self, response):
    topics = response.css('ul.topics')
    sections = topics.css('li.section')
    my_i = my_item.FileToDown()
    my_i['files_urls'] = [sections.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()]
    yield my_i
```

Answer (score 0):

It really hard to say without a lot more information, which I wouldn't be able to get without my own moogle account, but if the problem *is* that scrapy isn't automatically resolving the redirect, you probably want to add an extra step to your scraping pipeline where it structures a request to the *true* location of your file after requesting the https://moodle.some.ac.il/course/view.php?id=1032#section-0.

To sum up, the idea is write a function that takes in the response to requesting links like https://moodle.some.ac.il/course/view.php?id=1032#section-0 and uses the constent of this response to structure a request for links like https://moodle.some.ac.il/pluginfile.php/44033/mod_resource/content/1/my_file.docx, whose response is then handled by your function `parse_files`.

To figure out what this intermediate function must do in order to submit a request for your desired file url, I advise inspecting the body of the response that would be passed to your intermediate function and locating the xpath to where your file's url is.

Comment: thanks great idea, but isn't the `MEDIA_ALLOW_REDIRECTS = True` in the settings taking care of any redirection?